# Using if statement to change a pointer's location, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, chess

I am very new to C++. My compiler is g++ 12.2.0.

I am trying to use `if` statements to change what a pointer is assigned to. I don't understand why it stops working when adding an additional `if` statement. The issue is with `*movingPiece`, if `if(a==2){}` is commented out then there is no issue.

```
bool checkMove(int a , uint64_t s , uint64_t e, bool colour, uint64_t board, uint64_t black, uint64_t white, uint64_t pawn, uint64_t king, uint64_t queen, uint64_t bishop, uint64_t knight, uint64_t rook , uint64_t attackMap , uint64_t doubleAttackMap)
{
    uint64_t x ,z , *movingPiece;
    uint64_t *pieces = &white;
    board = board &~ s;
    if (colour){ uint64_t *pieces = &black; }
    if (a == 0){
        //pawn
        uint64_t *movingPiece = &pawn;
        *movingPiece = *movingPiece &~ s;
    }
    if(a == 1){
        //queen
        uint64_t *movingPiece = &queen;
        *movingPiece = *movingPiece &~ s;
    }
    if(a==2){
        uint64_t *movingPiece = &rook;
        *movingPiece = *movingPiece&~s;
    }

    *pieces = *pieces|e;
//----------------------------------------Code executes up until this point
    *movingPiece = *movingPiece|e;
//----------------------------------------Code beyond does not execute
    board = board|e;
    generateAttackMap(~colour, board, black, white, pawn, king, queen, bishop, knight, rook, &x , &z);
    if (x & king){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried using a `switch`, and assigning the variables in different places, but all result in code not executing.

The expectation is that the pointer will pass the modified variable into the code block at the bottom, into `attackMapGenerator`. This code is to check and see if the move will result in the player being in check after the move.

I am using `uint64_t` as I am working with bitwise logic on 64-bit integers.

Comment: `uint64_t *movingPiece = &pawn;` you are creating a new variable that ends its lifetime on the next `}` in your code or 2 lines down. This variable is not the same variable as the one declared here: `uint64_t x ,z , *movingPiece;` This is called shadowing.

Comment: Regarding the issue mentioned by @drescherjm, you have that in more places. Like for example `if (colour){uint64_t *pieces = &black;}`

Comment: @Michael Haney It is the first time when I have seen a function with 15 parameters.:)

Comment: And I'm sorry, but if you're "very new to C++" then you're too far ahead of the learning curve with this code. Pointers should not be in a beginners C++ course.

Comment: Add `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Werror -pedantic` when compiling. You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer in `*movingPiece = *movingPiece|e;`

Comment: Tip: Instead of `if (...) return true else return false` just do `return ...`. In your case you could `return !(x & king)`.

Comment: PSA: This function also has *way* too many arguments. If there's that many it should be operating on a `struct`, or even better, just be a regular function on a `class` where those can all be implied by context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring `movingPiece` inside of the `if` statements, so that's creating new variables, and the original `movingPiece` variable isn't modified. No memory address is ever being assigned to the original `movingPiece` variable, meaning that it is pointing to a random spot in memory. When you try to use `*movingPiece = *movingPiece|e` to modify the value that `movingPiece` is pointing at, you're accessing memory that you're not supposed to access. The Operating System sees this and throws a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), which ends up killing the program, hence why your code stops executing at that line.

Change the `if` statements to this:

```cpp
if (a == 0){
    movingPiece = &pawn;
}
else if(a == 1){
    movingPiece = &queen;
}
else if(a==2){
    movingPiece = &rook;
} 
else {
    std::cerr << "invalid a\n";
    std::exit(1);
}
*movingPiece &= ~s;
```

Comment: `switch` also a good candidate here, though with the `break` clutter that comes with.

Comment: @tadman A `switch` in a lambda that returns a reference would be pretty clean though. That'd also get rid of the pointer.

Comment: I run into a spererate error with way, "a value of type "uint64_t *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint64_t". I am still declaring `uint64_t *movingpiece;` at the start of the code block btw.

Comment: @MichaelHaney `uint64_t = *movingpiece` ? You mean `uint64_t* movingpiece;` right? Note that the answer first had `*movingPiece = &pawn;` etc in the assignments. If you now refresh the page, it will have `movingPiece = &pawn;` etc instead.

Comment: Absolute hero thank you very much! 
@Ted Lyngmo thank you for your help as well
To clarify my understanding with the error;

I declared `*movingPiece`, before, as mentioned, I was reasigning the variable "shadowing" the previous declaration, causing my error.
The change from *movingPiece --> movingPiece means that I am now directly changing the value of the movingPiece pointer rather than the data that it points to?
Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @MichaelHaney I mearly fixed a few typos, but you're welcome! If you'd like to work with references instead of pointers, [here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/xE6vK6dva)